# ABP startup template MVC (model view controller)

Tags: abp

how can I use startup template MVC (Model view controller) not razor pages in ABP framework

I found there is no command for it in documentation

Answer (score 0):

By default abp uses razor pages, there is no option to use traditional mvc in the cli, if you want to use mvc you can add services.AddControllersWithViews(); in the services and app.UseEndpoints configuration in the pipeline configuration, additionally create the Controllers, Views and ViewModels folder in the web layer.